# Internship verbal offer but no offer letter

Tags: job-offer, internship, human-resources, relocation, start-date

I received an offer over the phone for an internship out of state. I was told my salary, start date, and last day to accept the offer.

I know the company provides housing assistance, so I asked if could get any help with moving. The HR lady said she can do that for me.

It has been two weeks since I spoke to her and the last day to accept the offer is in a week.

Would it make sense to email the HR lady and ask when I should be expecting the letter? Or should I just remain patient?

Comment: @JeffQuick Did you post the right link? I'm struggling to see how that question is related at all.

Comment: Sorry I'm struggle with the english language at times, maybe not.

Comment: Turns out HR forgot to sent me the email and my deadline to accept has been extended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It not only makes sense, it's necessary.

**If you don't have an offer in writing, you don't have an offer.**

Simply state that you need something in writing to respond with acceptance.